# What are the silver Shy Guys for?

Tags: yoshis-new-island

I saw a silver Shy Guy, and being a Yoshi, I figured maybe eating him was the way to go. I just got a normal egg out of the deal, so I am wondering if maybe eating him was the wrong choice. It's so sparkly! What does it mean!

Comment: Are you sure it was a normal egg? Silver Shy Guys should give you metal eggs. Metal eggs are "heavier" which means they allow you to sink in water.

Comment: Yeah, it was. He was silver and flashy and flying. And I ate him.

Comment: I think you get stuff if you hit them with multiple eggs, but that's just experience from the first game, not with this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you throw eggs at the silver Shy Guy, you will receive lives in return.

Comment: I will add that I was very tempted to eat the little fella until I remembered how things worked in the original game